# calculate the number of bars between the first bar and the last bar that meets the condition

Tags: pine-script

trying to make an indicator that draw a line on last bar meets the condition but the problem is its draw a line on every bar that meets the condition.
how to find the last bar where the condition was true and calculate the number of bars between the first bar and the last bar that meets the condition ?
i tried to use the measure tool to count the bars between the first bar and last one the condition was true but i need to do this by the code

```
  LP=low
//p is an input from the user which is a price
if((LP==p))
   line.new......
```

Answer (score 2):

This code saves the bar number where the condition first becomes true and whenever it becomes true again, it refreshes the line's coordinates:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
// Use your condition here.
cond = rising(close, 5)

var int firstBar = na
var line ln = na
if cond
    if na(firstBar)
        // Save first bar where cond is true.
        firstBar := bar_index
    if na(ln)
        // Line wasn't drawn yet; draw it.
        ln := line.new(firstBar, high, bar_index, high, width = 5)
        // Fudge return type of `if` block so compiler doesn't complain (thx midtownsk8rguy for the trick).
        int(na)
    else
        // Line was already drawn a first time, change its coordinates.
        line.set_xy2(ln, bar_index, high)
        int(na)
plotchar(cond, "cond", "•", location.top)
```

[image]